# Linux How to Check if list_head is empty?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I saw that linux kernel is using `struct list_head` to save the children of a process.

What if the process has no forked children? will it return null or not? how may I check if a process has no children?

Comment: Your post is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). But to answer the question of your title: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/list.h#L280.

Comment: @wxz thanks, don't you want to post answer and get the points (already solved it) btw please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462685/kernel-pointer-to-current-process?noredirect=1#comment119242035_67462685

Comment: Yes, I had added a comment to that post last night as well. Was there something specific you wanted me to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file [`include/linux/list.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/list.h#L1) contains many useful functions for manipulating lists. One of the functions in this file is [`list_empty()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/list.h#L280), which returns the result of checking whether the list `head` is equal to itself ( `head -> next`), if true, the list is empty.

If the child process list isn't empty, you can use the [`list_for_each_entry_safe`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/list.h#L714) macro/function to iterate through the list safely.